# Count the occurrences of every word in C

Tags: c, counting, word-processor

I want to count the occurrences of every word of this small text " A broken heart of a broken mind ."

Every word of this text is in 2d `array[100][20]` in which 100 is the `max_words` and 20 is the `max_word_length`.  And I have a pointers `array[100]` in which every pointer points the word. I can't find a clever way to count the same words,
for example

```
a: 2 times
broken: 2 times
heart: 1 time
mind: 1 time
. : 1 time
```

These would be the pointers and the words array:

```
POINTERS ARRAY                      WORDS ARRAY
point0(points "a")                  a
point1(points "broken")             broken
point2(points "heart")              heart
point3(points "of")                 of
point4 (points "a")                 mind
point5(points "broken")             .
point6(points "mind")               \0\0\0\0\0
point7(points ".")                  \0\0\0\0\0
NULL                                ..
NULL
..
NULL                                \0\0\0\0\0
```

Side note: Every word is lowercase.

```
void frequence_word(char *pointers[], int frequence_array[]) {
  int word = 0;
  int i;
  int count = 1;
  int check[MAX_WORDS];

  for (word = 0; word < MAX_WORDS; word++) {
    check[word] = -1;
  }

  for (word = 0; word < MAX_WORDS; word++) {
    count = 1;

    for (i = word + 1; i < MAX_WORDS; i++) {

      if (pointers[word + 1] != NULL
          && strcmp(pointers[word], pointers[i]) == 0) {
        count++;
        check[i] = 0;
      }

    }
    if (check[word] != 0) {
      check[word] = count;
    }

  }
}
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: Hello there and welcome to stack overflow! In order for us to answer your question, could you show us a little bit about what you've tried so far? Additionally, I don't think I understood your second paragraph... What does it mean?

Comment: @PedroMartinsdeSouza : His second paragraph is his list of pointers.  Only found out when editing :)

Comment: thank you! I am new and I dont know exactly how I can handle of it!

Comment: I don't see the point of the pointer array.  `char *pointers[][2]`  Why is the second dimension 2?

Comment: Yes I would erase but I need it in another step.

Comment: If you pass in a pointer array of 8 items and a frequence array of 6 items (because the words array only has 6) then how do you know which index in the frequency array belongs to the word "mind" since it is pointer array index 6 but only index 4 in the words array?  What I am saying is, don't you need to pass in the words array so you know which index of the the frequency array to update?

Comment: In this function I can ONLY use the pointers array. The word_array is in order to print every word in a next step. In this function I dont need it. I am wondering if there is a way with 1 for loop or using the strstr function to count the same words using only the pointers array!

Comment: Any ideas please??

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a use case for [`strstr`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/). You can call `strstr`, then iteratively reassign to the original string until NULL is reached.

```c
const char substring[] = "A broken heart of a broken mind";
const char* total = ...;

const char* result;
long count = 0;
while (result = strstr(total, substring)) {
    count++;
    total += (sizeof(substring) - 1);
}
```

I think this is mostly self-explanetory, but I will explain this line:

```c
total += (sizeof(substring) - 1);
```

It takes advantage of the fact that `sizeof` on arrays returns the array length. Thus, sizeof on a character array returns the number of characters in it. We subtract one to ignore the null terminator.